# Updating php mysql_query() to prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

according to some older tutorials i created a formular that stores some information into a mysql DB with mysql_query(). 
But now i've read some posts, that say one shouldn't use mysql_query() any longer so i've tried to "translate" my old code. 
But afterwards it doesn't work anylonger and no new entries are stored in my DB.
Can you help please?

```
<?php
    require '../db/connect.php';

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
      echo "Fehler bei der Verbindung: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit();
    }

    $flightDate = $_POST['flightDate'];
    $planeID = $_POST['planeID'];
    $planeType = $_POST['planeType'];
    $pilot = $_POST['pilot'];
    $passengers = $_POST['passengers'];


/*  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `flights`
                (`flightDate`, `planeID`,`planeType`, `pilot`, `passengers`)
            VALUES(
                '" .$flightDate. "',
                '" .$planeID. "',
                '" .$planeType. "',
                '" .$pilot. "',
                '" .$passengers. "'
            )";
    mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());
*/



    // prepared statement   
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO flights
                                        (flightDate, planeID,planeType, pilot, passengers)
                                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
      $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $flightDate, $planeID, $planeType, $pilot, $passengers);
      $stmt->execute();
      echo "Anzahl der veränderten Datensätze : " . $stmt->affected_rows;
      $stmt->close();
    }

    $mysqli->close();
```

Seems like there is something wrong with my variables. If i call the php file directly in the browser i get a lot of error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: flightDate in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptomysql\try_2\ajax\addFlight.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: planeID in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptomysql\try_2\ajax\addFlight.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: planeType in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptomysql\try_2\ajax\addFlight.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: pilot in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptomysql\try_2\ajax\addFlight.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: passengers in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptomysql\try_2\ajax\addFlight.php on line 13
Anzahl der veränderten Datensätze : -1
```

I'm using the following jquery function to pass the values from my form to the php:

```
//add flight to db
$('#flightSubmit').on('click', function(){
    var flightDate = ($.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $('#flightDateInput').datepicker("getDate")));
    var planeID = $('input#planeIDInput').val();
    var planeType = $('input#planeTypeInput').val();
    var pilot = $('input#pilotInput').val();
    var passengers = $('input#passengersInput').val();
    $.post('ajax/addFlight.php', {flightDate: flightDate, planeID: planeID, planeType: planeType, pilot: pilot, passengers: passengers}, function(data){
        });
});
```

Comment: `$flightDate = ""$_POST['flightDate'];` remove the quotes there.

Comment: removed it.
in the chrome dev console's network panel i can see a "canceled" status" for my php file.

Comment: This is why I migrated from mysqli to PDO. It's a little different, but so much simpler.

Comment: @Herbert did you meant mysql_* which is what the OP is migrating from ? because MySQLi and PDO are both easy and great.

Comment: @Prix: Nope, I meant MySQLi. I never much enjoyed working with it esp. in the context of prepared statements and bound parameters.

Comment: @Herbert well I like both and personally use PDO but to tell or use as example for beginners, I think MySQLi is the easiest.

Comment: Did you checked the output of **print_r($_POST);die();**? (Put on top of your page)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error? 
Or it just dont insert int o the db?
Could you please var_dump your $_POST and $stmt like this

```
<?php
    require '../db/connect.php';

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
      echo "Fehler bei der Verbindung: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit();
    }

    $flightDate = $_POST['flightDate'];
    $planeID = $_POST['planeID'];
    $planeType = $_POST['planeType'];
    $pilot = $_POST['pilot'];
    $passengers = $_POST['passengers'];

var_dump($_POST);

    // prepared statement   
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO flights
                                        (flightDate, planeID,planeType, pilot, passengers)
                                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
var_dump($stmt);
    if($stmt) {
      $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $flightDate, $planeID, $planeType, $pilot, $passengers);
      $stmt->execute();
      echo "Anzahl der veränderten Datensätze : " . $stmt->affected_rows;
      $stmt->close();
    }

    $mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not related to mysqli, you will get this error if there is no posted data (empty).

you just have to wrap your code with

`if (!empty($_POST) { }`

Answer (score 0):

You have a mixture of `mysql_*` calls and `mysqli_*` calls.  This will *not* work.  Fix that *first*.